# using constructor in abstract class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, constructor, abstract-class

I have a class as follows:

```
public abstract class cDBBase
{
     public cDBBase()
     {
         some codes
      }
      Some codes;
 }
```

I have another class

```
public class cSQL : cDBBase
{
     public void cSQL()
     {
         Some codes;
     }
}
```

Why  do I get error "member name cannot be the same name as their enclosing type" on the child class constructor?

Here are complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Uploader
{
    public abstract class cDBBaseClass
    {
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
        public string DBName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ConnString;

        public cDBBaseClass(string serverName, string dBName, string userName, string password)
        {
            ServerName = serverName;
            DBName = dBName;
            UserName = userName;
            Password = password;
        }

        public abstract string SetConnString();

        public abstract void SetConn();
    }
}
```

and the child class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace Uploader.Classes
{
    public class cSQL:cDBBaseClass
    {
        private SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();

        public cSQL()
        {
            SetConnString();
            SetConn();
        }


        public override string SetConnString()
        {
            return "data source = " + this.ServerName +
                   "; database = " + this.DBName +
                   "; User ID = " + this.UserName +
                   "; Password = " + this.Password;
        }

        public override void SetConn()
        {
            Conn.ConnectionString = this.ConnString;
        }

        public SqlDataReader ExecSQL(string Query)
        {
            using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(SetConnString()))
            {
                Conn.Open();   
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query , Conn);
                return cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }


        public SqlDataReader ExecStoredProcedure(string SPName)
        {
            using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(SetConnString()))
            {
                Conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SPName, Conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                return cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You probably just don't want the `void`.

Comment: OP, I see you've asked a number of questions but accepted no answers. You should accept the answer that best resolves your question by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: When I take out the void I get the error "cDBBase does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Comment: @tnw the one that answered the question entered it as a comment which does not give me the option to select it. My other question I answered it myself, should I select it? My other questions are not answered yet.

Comment: @Mariann I'm unable to reproduce that error you posted after removing `void`. See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/84oDyb

Comment: @Grant Winney Thanks for your reply! I edited my question and provided more details! I wonder if you could find its problem! really appreciated!

Comment: @tnw I just provided more detail to the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're defining a method `cSQL` which has the exact same name as the class it's contained in. You can't do that. Did you mean to make a constructor instead? Just remove `void`.

Comment: yes I need a constructor and I don't understand why it does not accept it. The constructor has to the exact name as their class, right?

Comment: @Mariann Because you aren't defining a constructor, you're defining a method by giving it a return type, `void` in this case. A constructor does indeed need to have the same name as its class, you just need to remove `void` to make it a constructor instead of a method.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It does not return any value it just calls couple of other functions, I tried removing the void and it gives me the above error!

Comment: @Grant Winney It is the same as cDBBase! Sorry I wanted to make the question as simple as possible! :)

Answer (score 1):

tnw really did fix your original issue, but to fix your other issue, your class must accept the same parameters as the base class, and pass them to it:

```
public class cSQL : cDBBaseClass
{
    private SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();

    public cSQL(string serverName, string dBName, string userName, string password)
        : base(serverName, dBName, userName, password)
    {
        SetConnString();
        SetConn();
    }

    ...
```